# Same id inserted for all records and repeats as many times as the foreach loops

Tags: php, foreach

```
{
............
............
$order_details="INSERT INTO .....";
mysql_query($order_details);
$o_id_detail[]=mysql_insert_id();
}

$prev_id=implode(',',$o_id_detail);
$last_id=explode(',',$prev_id);
foreach($last_id as $last)
{
    $last;
    foreach($addon_price as $a_p=>$p)
    { 
        echo $a_p;
        foreach($p as $m)
        {

            $addon_id= $m['id'];
            echo $m['addon_name'];
            echo $m['deposit'];
            echo $m['ppd'];
            echo $m['pp_eight'];
            echo $m['pp_six'];

            $addon_total = $m['deposit']+$m['ppd']+$m['pp_eight']+$m['pp_six'];
            echo $addon_total;

            $addon_detail="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail_addon 
                                (OrderID,addOns_id,addOns_price) 
                            VALUES ('$last','$addon_id','$addon_total')";
            if(!empty($addon_id)){
                mysql_query($addon_detail)or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }     
   }   
}
}
```

Now, Im getting ($last) inserted as many times as the foreach loops( foreach($addon_price as $a_p=>$p)).
How to restrict ($last) id form inserting any rows again if the ($last)id for a specific addon_item already exist?

Edited part:

```
$o_id_detail=mysql_insert_id();

    foreach($addon_price as $a_p=>$p)
               { 
                echo $a_p;
                   foreach($p as $m)
                   {

                       $addon_id= $m['id'];
                       echo $m['addon_name'];
                       echo $m['deposit'];
                       echo $m['ppd'];
                       echo $m['pp_eight'];
                       echo $m['pp_six'];
                  $addon_total=$m['deposit']+$m['ppd']+$m['pp_eight']+$m['pp_six'];
                   echo $addon_total;




$addon_detail="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail_addon (OrderID,addOns_id,addOns_price) VALUES ('$o_id_detail','$addon_id','$addon_total')";
if(!empty($addon_id))
                {
                mysql_query($addon_detail)or die(mysql_error());


              }
            }     
         }   
}
```

FULL CODE:

```
 $user="INSERT INTO tbl_users (email,name,contact,register_date) VALUES ('$email','$c_name','$contact',NOW())";
  mysql_query($user)or die(mysql_error());

             $u_id=mysql_insert_id();
             }
              else
             {
                 $u_id=$user_id;
             }
             $insert="INSERT INTO tbl_order(id,customer_name,contact_number,remark_by_customer,pay_type,amount,Create_Dt) VALUES ('$u_id','$c_name','$contact',' $c_remark','$payment_method','$grand_sum',now())";

mysql_query($insert)or die(mysql_error());

             //tbl_orderdetail
             //getting car ids
             // $car_list= implode(',',$cars);
             $o_id=mysql_insert_id();
             foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$val)
             {
                 $unit=strip_tags($key);
                 $new_pickup=$val['location'];
                 $new_dropoff=$val['dropoff'];
                 $cars=$val['car_id'];

                 //pickup table
                  mysql_select_db($database_bumi_conn, $bumi_conn);
                  $query_orderdetail="SELECT * FROM tbl_pickup_location WHERE pickup_location='$new_pickup'";
                  $result_orderdetail=mysql_query($query_orderdetail)or die(mysql_error());
                  $row_orderdetail=mysql_fetch_array($result_orderdetail);
                  $new_pick_id=$row_orderdetail['pickup_id'];

                  //dropoff table
                   mysql_select_db($database_bumi_conn, $bumi_conn);
                  $query_orderdetail_2="SELECT * FROM tbl_dropoff WHERE dropoff_location='$new_dropoff'";
                  $result_orderdetail_2=mysql_query($query_orderdetail_2)or die(mysql_error());
                  $row_orderdetail_2=mysql_fetch_array($result_orderdetail_2);
                  $new_dropoff_id=$row_orderdetail_2['dropoff_id'];



            $new_date_1=$val['date_value'];
            $new_date_2=$val['date_value_2'];
            $total_renting_days=$val['total_days'];




      $order_details="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail (OrderID,pickup_id,dropoff_id,pickup_date,return_date,renting_days,carName_id,Car_Unitprice) VALUES ('$o_id','$new_pick_id',' $new_dropoff_id','$new_date_1','$new_date_2','$total_renting_days','$cars','$unit')";
if(!empty($cars)&&($unit)){
  mysql_query($order_details)or die(mysql_error());
      $o_id_detail=mysql_insert_id();
      echo '>>>'.$o_id_detail.'<<<';
             }}


            foreach($addon_price as $a_p=>$p)
                                   { 
                                    echo $a_p;
                                       foreach($p as $m)
                                       {

                                           $addon_id= $m['id'];
                                           echo $m['addon_name'];
                                           echo $m['deposit'];
                                           echo $m['ppd'];
                                           echo $m['pp_eight'];
                                           echo $m['pp_six'];
                                      $addon_total=$m['deposit']+$m['ppd']+$m['pp_eight']+$m['pp_six'];
                                       echo $addon_total;




            $addon_detail="INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail_addon (OrderID,addOns_id,addOns_price) VALUES ('$o_id_detail','$addon_id','$addon_total')";
               if(!empty($addon_id)){
  mysql_query($addon_detail)or die(mysql_error());


                                  }
                                              }     
                                   }   
             } // foreach($addon_price as $a_p=>$p)
```

Comment: I don't see `$last` being used in the `iNSERT` statement.

Comment: Why are you putting `$o_id_detail` in the `INSERT` statement? That's an array, it makes no sense to expand it into a string in the SQL.

Comment: Why do you need the `$prev_id` and `$last_id` arrays? Isn't `$last_id` the same as `$o_id_detail`?

Comment: Why don't you just perform the requires loops and insertions during the first loop you do? Otherwise you're populating an array based on your first lot of insertions, then looping through the results from each of them to do another one

Comment: @Barmar,yes the value of $o_id_detail is same as $last but the reason why I did in that way is, without them,the id retrieved from mysql_insert_id inserting the same id for all records.

Comment: You're talking nonsense. If the value is the same, then it can't make a difference which one you use.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique composite index on `(OrderID, addOns_id)` to your table. Then use

```
$addon_detail="INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_orderdetail_addon 
                    (OrderID,addOns_id,addOns_price) 
                VALUES ('$last','$addon_id','$addon_total')";
```

The `IGNORE` option means that if there's a duplicate key it will silently skip the insertion attempt.

Comment: I couldn't add unique index for both because there can be same OrderID and same addon_id in this table as well. But for the same OrderID there shouldn't be any same addon_id

Comment: A composite index allows each column to be duplicated, only the combination has to be unique.

Comment: please look at the edited part without first foreach, where I omited those $prev,$last foreach and using $o_id_detail straight. It inserts correct number of rows but  using the same id($o_id_detail) for all rows.

Comment: Why shouldn't it use the same `$o_id_detail` for all rows? That's what you wrote. What do you expect it to use instead?

Comment: I uploaded my full coding. You would get what I mean if you could look at it.Thanks

Comment: Please say what you want it to do, so I can understand how that's different from what it actually does.

Comment: The name of the column in `tbl_orderdetail_addon` is `OrderID`. Shouldn't it contain `$o_id` instead of `$o_id_detail`?

Comment: Is there another column in `tbl_orderdetail_addon` that contains the foreign key to `tbl_orderdetail`

Comment: okay, now that $o_id_detail itself inside a foreach,so it may return more than one id .So all I want is to insert into tbl_orderdetail_addon as many times as the id returned from there. Thats how it works now but instead of getting different ids from $o_id_detail it returns the same for all rows. I know it's because of the foreach that rsides inside which is(   foreach($addon_price as $a_p=>$p)) .But I've no idea on how to fix it. If I place the insertion before this foreach then  couldn't get their data.

Comment: You've totally lost me. I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you.